How to save files onto another user's OneDrive Using Microsoft Graph
I have a web app where I would like the administrator to specify a Office 365 account (by storing the name and password) whose OneDrive would be used to store common files.
I've gone back and forth about whether to use Azure Files.  For cost reasons, our organization has free OneDrive but not free Azure Files.  So we would like to use that to save money.
However, when I look at sample code such as this:
 public async Task UploadFileToOneDrive(string filePath, string onedriveFolderPath)
        {
            string accessToken = await GetAccessToken();

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }));

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath($"{onedriveFolderPath}/{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
            }
        }

I get a problem with Me.Drive.Root.
I can't find code to access another users account.  Also, I am using Microsoft Identity to login, so I would also wonder about the permissions needed.  I could give all the users in the system access to the OneDrive.
To summarize:

Is this a realistic idea, or should I use Azure Files and just pay the extra money?  Like I said, I could just manually give users permissions since its an internal application without a lot of users.

How could I access another user's drive and make the appropriate call?


Tried calling Me Root and I get an error that does not exist as a valid call.
